# Java Scanner requires two inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have rearranged my code several different ways with no luck. I think that the problem is that I don't fully understand the Scanner in Java. Either way, here is my code. It starts by printing a menu from an array passed to the method. Next it should wait for the user's input and parse the users input into an integer.

```
int menuLength = menuItems.length;

Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); //Create a new scanner object
int userInput = 0; //Initialize the input variable
int i=0; //Initialize the counter variable

for (i=0; i < menuLength; ++i) {//loop until it has reached the end of the menu
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + menuItems[i]);//Print menu items
}

System.out.print(">>");

userInput = Character.getNumericValue(scnr.next().charAt(0));

while ((userInput < 1) || (userInput > menuLength)) { //Loop while the value is not a valid selection
        System.out.println("Error, please select from the menu options.");
        while (scnr.hasNextInt()!=true) { //Loop while the value is not an integer
            System.out.println("Error, please select from the menu options.");
            //LOOP TO PROVIDE THE MENU
            for (i=0; i < menuLength; ++i) {//loop until it has reached the end of the menu
                System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + menuItems[i]);//Print menu items
            }
            System.out.println(">>");
            scnr.next(); //Get the next value
        }

        for (i=0; i < menuLength; ++i) {//loop until it has reached the end of the menu
            System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + menuItems[i]);//Print menu items
        }

        System.out.print(">>");
        userInput =  scnr.nextInt(); //Get the next value
    }
```

The code stops here and requires the user to input something, press enter, then input something again, and press enter before it moves to the next line. I simply want the user to be able to enter a value, press enter, and then it primes an error trap loop.

Comment: try with scnr.nextLine()

Comment: Your code (with tweaks to make it run) doesn't make me enter two things.  Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Scanner has hasNextInt() and nextInt(). Read the javadoc.

Comment: Thank you, could it just be the Eclipse compiler? I am running it from the console window inside of Eclipse.

Comment: I doubt it; I'm also using eclipse.  It's probably got more to do with whatever your next line is, or whatever you might have previously done with your scanner.  It's very difficult to say without a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, there is more of the code. If I put a print statement under the userInput assignment, it doesn't print anything. That's why I was lead to think that the execution stopped at that line for some reason.

Comment: I'm finding that if I run the method now, it works fine. When I figure out what is causing this I will post. Thanks for the help!